# How can I fix my long supertabular with a 2-columns layout?

Tags: longtable, two-column, supertabular

I tried many solutions for solving my problem, last of which taken here.
I need to insert a long supertabular (80 rows) in a 2-columns layout document.
 Currently my table doen't continue on the 2nd column, but goes over the bottom margin of the page and is clipped.

This is my source:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn,twoside,openright]{article}
\usepackage{supertabular,booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphics,graphicx,color,xcolor,makeidx,setspace,html,htmllist}
%\usepackage{latexsym,ifthen}
\usepackage{stfloats,dblfloatfix}
\usepackage[small]{caption}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

\begin{document}
.. other setions...
\section{current section} 

\subsection{Material and methods}
... text of the section...
\begin{table}
\small
\tablefirsthead{
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{\,}l}{App} & 
\multicolumn{1}{@{\,}l}{Category} & 
\multicolumn{1}{@{\,}l}{Free} & 
\multicolumn{1}{@{\,}l}{Rating} & 
\multicolumn{1}{@{\,}l}{DL} & 
\multicolumn{1}{@{\,}l}{Class} \\
\midrule
}
\tablehead{%
\multicolumn{6}{c}%
{{\bfseries  ... continued}} \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{\,}l}{App} & 
\multicolumn{1}{@{\,}l}{Category} & 
\multicolumn{1}{@{\,}l}{Free} & 
\multicolumn{1}{@{\,}l}{Rating} & 
\multicolumn{1}{@{\,}l}{DL} & 
\multicolumn{1}{@{\,}l}{Class} \\
\midrule
}
%
\tabletail {%
\midrule 
\multicolumn{6}{r}{{Continue...}} \\ 
\midrule
}
\tablelasttail{%
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r}{{Concluded}} \\ 
\bottomrule
}
\begin{supertabular}{p{0.15\textwidth}@{\,}l@{\,}l@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}l}
ACLS sim 2012 & medical & no & 4,2 & 7500 & - \\ \hline
... other rows...
Workout Trainer & H. \& Fit. & yes & 4,3 & 7500000 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

What's wrong?
I've also tried to delete the table environment and move the \small command into supertabular environment: in this case, the table goes on the 2nd column (andh on the next page), but the table exceeds the right margin of each column, except the first.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi Mico, I found the following commands instead the template  I use, hope they answer to you questions:
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn,twoside,openright]{article}
\protect\twocolumn[

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @cryingshadow : you are right. I added all usepackage commands I've found. However, I'm a newbie in LaTex and I used a template provided by a new publisher, so if something else is needed, don't hesitate to ask for.

Comment: When loading the `dblfloatfix` package, I get the following error: `Command \c@dblbotnumber already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.` Does the MWE compile exactly as stated here on your machine?

Comment: Yes, I obtain the same error. 
I didn't fix it is caused by the templated I had to use.

Comment: Where is this template from? Why do you have to use it? Can you ask the template's author(s) to fix this error? It does not make much sense to work with a template that does not compile without errors.

Comment: I'm too late for doing this, I need to submit my paper within tomorrow. 
However, I'm quite sure that these errors don't influence the table, since were displayed also before I added my table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to tell with certainty why the long table isn't allowing a column break, since you've only provided some short fragments of that table.

The code below implements the following suggestions:

- I use `%%` (double comment symbols) to comment out instructions that are counterproductive to getting your document typeset.
- Don't load both `graphics` and `graphicx`. Similarly, don't load both `color` and `xcolor`.
- Since you're using the `booktabs` package, do *not* use `\hline` instructions. Instead, consider using `\midrule` to get better spacing around the horizontal lines.
- Most importantly: Do *not* start a `table` environment to encase a `supertabular` environment. As stated earlier, it's not possible to diagnose with certainty the cause of your main problem with certainty, since you haven't provided enough material to make the `supertabular` environment exceed the height of one column. However, I'm pretty sure that it's the erroneous use of a `table` environment that's causing this problem.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn,twoside,openright]{article}
\usepackage{supertabular,booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, %% graphics,  % do not load both 'graphics' and 'graphicx'
    graphicx,%%color, % do not load both 'color' and 'xcolor'
    xcolor,makeidx,setspace}  
    %%,html,htmllist % why on earth are you loading these two packages?
%\usepackage{latexsym,ifthen} % "latexsym" package has been obsolete for 20+ years 
\usepackage{stfloats}%%,dblfloatfix} % Do you actually need 'dblfloatfix' package?
\usepackage[small]{caption}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

\begin{document}
\dots  other setions \dots 

\section{Current section} 

\subsection{Material and methods}
\dots  text of the section \dots 

%%\begin{table}  %% not needed! In fact, it causes an error
\begingroup %%this is new; it localizes effect of "\small"
% reset "\tabcolsep":    % no need for 17 [!!] instances of "@{\,}", right?
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt} 
\small
\tablefirsthead{%
\toprule
App & Category & Free & 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Rating} & 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{DL} & 
Class \\
\midrule
}
\tablehead{%
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\bfseries  \dots  continued} \\[1ex]
\toprule
App & Category & Free & 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Rating} & 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{DL} & 
Class \\
\midrule
}
%
\tabletail {%
\midrule 
\multicolumn{6}{r@{}}{Continued\dots} \\ 
\midrule
}
\tablelasttail{%
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r@{}}{Concluded} \\ 
\bottomrule
}
\begin{supertabular}{@{}p{0.15\textwidth}llccl}
ACLS sim 2012 & medical & no & 4,2 & 7500 & - \\ 
\midrule
\dots  other rows\dots \\

Workout Trainer & H.\,\& Fit. & yes & 4,3 & 7500000 &  \\ \midrule
\end{supertabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```